# Ajax call to wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and am trying to create a simple call that can be called from an ajax page. I know how to do this with PHP but am unable to do it with wordpress.

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Jed Plugin
*/

function func_rate()
{

    $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body (wp_remote_get("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=ZAR"));
  $pos = strpos($data,'class=bld>');
   echo substr($data,$pos+10,7);

}

 add_action( 'get_value', 'func_rate' );
```

I need to create a simple ajax call to this

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://www.forexforecasts.co.za/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php",
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'get_value'
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        alert(response)
    }
});
```

Comment: You should read the [**codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), Wordpress has very specific requirements and methods when doing ajax requests to plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: like adeneo said in his comment. Wordpress has build in methods for handeling Ajax requests, Just change your action to:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_value', 'func_rate' ); //for loged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_value', 'func_rate' ); //for guests
```

And at the end of your code in the function func_rate() add wp_die(); to prevent WP from running after the ajax request is done.

Lastly, change the url in your ajax request to ajaxurl. this var should be predefined by WP.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I need to make the call from an external site not from the actual WP site. So how can I use a predefined ajax url

Comment: I didn't test this. but you can try to do the request from the external site to {destenation_domain}/wp_admin/admin-ajax.php. Don't forget to add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {source_domain}'); to the destination site.